# How to get static file directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my solution, I have static file directory at project `ApiCon` and my code is need to get static file directory is in project `BLL` and the file path url is `/image/myimg.png`.

Now that file can show in front end completely. I need to delete my image in static file directory when I call Api in controller, But I can't get path to delete that file.

How to get static file directory?

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

P.S. I need not to use `Directory.GetParent()` for find directory in other project.

Comment: Sorry but what is a _static file directory_? Do you want to delete a file or a directory? Your code works on files.

Comment: static file directory is mean this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x ,  I need to delete file in staticfiles directory.

Comment: Why don't you save the _static file directory_ path in config yourself, and read it from there? If at any point, the path is changed, you'd need only to change the value in config. Your code will remain the same.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

Static files, while they should be located in the application folder, can be placed **in whatever folder you want**.

They could be in:

- `application_root/files/`
- `application_root/files/static/`
- `application_root/superman/batman/robinhood/`

On the plus side, you get to put them wherever you want, even in multiple location. On the down side, **there is no default static file directory**.

Which means you'll have to keep track of the directory itself. The best way to store such information is in the `web.config` file of your application.

---

**1. Add the config key in the `<appSettings>` of your web.config file.**

```
<add key="StaticFileDirectory" value="MyStaticFiles" />
```

**2. Add a reference to `System.Configuration` in your project.**

It's listed under `Assemblies > Framework`.

**3. Retrieve the config value.**

```
string foldername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StaticFileDirectory"];
```

**4. Convert it to an absolute path.**

```
string absoluteFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, foldername);
```

**5. Use it as you want to.**

```
string absoluteFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(absoluteFolderPath, filename);

if (File.Exists(absoluteFilePath))
{
    File.Delete(absoluteFilePath);
}
```

Comment: But doesn't the documentation list a default [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#serve-static-files)?

Comment: @SimplyGed: It creates folders with default names, but I'm not seeing any part where the retrieval of files is done based on a filename (without path) and an implicitly decided default folder (it always expects the developer to know whether he's looking for e.g. the "images" directory).

Comment: @SimplyGed: Is it possible you were referring to "directories with _default names_" as opposed to "_default directories_ (which inherently have a fixed name)"?

Comment: A minor nit, but the question was tagged asp.net core, so this answer isn't directly applicable.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this issue by this way.
This function will search all subdirectories inside the given folder path ex:"C:\Users\NBY81HC\Desktop\hello" to return the file you want.

```
foreach (string file_path in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\NBY81HC\Desktop\hello", "test.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
   Console.WriteLine(file_path);//Return C:\Users\NBY81HC\Desktop\hello\aa\a2\test.txt
   File.Delete(file_path);
}
```